# webkit click on nearest select fires mouseenter/hover event

Tags: jquery, webkit, hover, html-select, mouseenter

I've got a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fjjr6sq2/1/ which is really simple function

```
$(".dropdown li").on("mouseenter", function(){
    $(this).find(".layer").addClass("active");
}).on("mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).find(".layer").removeClass("active");
});
```

which shows and hides the layer when you mouseenter/mouseleave particular list item. If you exchange the mouseenter/mouseleave with hover function the result is likewise.

This problem **exists only on webkit browsers** so please use Chrome if you want to reproduce properly.

**The problem:**

When I select option 3 or 4 from the select list then the layer shows suddenly and of course it should not. Layer should only show itself (gain/loose active class) when I hover on the particular list item.

I wasn't able to make any workaround and Im curious about is it something wrong with the CSS part (maybe I lack a rule or two) or maybe it's a webkit bug. I've searched google but without any success on narrowing the cause of such behavior.

Unfortunately I cannot use custom select plugin that would presumably fix the issue.

Please advice.

**Update**

I cannot record that behavior so I thought images will be sufficent for this case.

When I open the select list and then choose option 4 the layer opens itself as I would click on the item that's in vertical line with my cursor. So placing cursor below item 3 after opening select list will open layer for item 3.

Check the images here:

https://imageshack.com/a/ZnKz/1

Red dot represents the point where I click.

My Chrome version is: 38.0.2125.111 m

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this just by selecting 3 or 4. I did notice that if you select a high number (like 10), then select a number right above it (like 8 or 9), that leaves your mouse over an li box when the select list closes, which will of course make a layer appear. This doesn't happen in Firefox because the select list always goes down. Is this the behavior you're struggling with?

Comment: @cjspurg I've updated the issue with some additional input and images that will hopefuly allow to understand the problem better.

Comment: I can repro this with Chrome on a PC, Chrome on a Mac does not do this. So far the closest I can get to an answer is adding `pointer-events: none` to the `.layer` class, but it still flickers. Somehow after selecting an option, the mouse hovers the layer briefly. I think this is a Chrome bug.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by setting a css property for 1 second

```
$("select").click(function() {
    $('.layer').css('pointer-events', 'none');
    window.setTimeout( showpointer, 1000 );
});

function showpointer(){
    $('.layer').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.